# How to give width, height, x and y coordinates in generating pdf from html using JSPDF new html API

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf, jspdf-autotable, pdf-to-html

I have been using JSPDF to generate pdf document based on some html. Earlier using jspdf fromHTML Api, we could give margins like this

```
      var margins2 = {
      top: 415,
      bottom: 10,
      left: 55,
      width: 300
  };

  doc.fromHTML(reactListContent, margins2.left, margins2.top, {
    'width': margins2.width,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
  }, margins2);
```

But, in the new .html API , how can i provide margins, width and height.
The new API is like

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
pdf.html(document.getElementById('html'), {
    callback: function (pdf) {
      console.log("how to get margins");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code of jspdf.debug.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.debug.js), [`html.js`](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_html.js.html) has the options for x and y offsets.

```
opt: {
    filename: 'file.pdf',
    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    enableLinks: true,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    html2canvas: {},
    jsPDF: {}
}
```

So you can set the x and y coordinates like this:

```
pdf.html(document.getElementById('html'), {
    x: 36,
    y: 36,
    callback: function () {
        // pdf.save('test.pdf');
        window.open(pdf.output('bloburl')); // to debug
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I can't do the same by modifying the `margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]`. Looks like they are [still working on this issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1176#issuecomment-447640950). So the short answer is **NOT YET**.

A work-around is to calculate the scale of html2canvas by margin:

```
let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
let margin = 36; // narrow margin - 12.7 mm
let srcwidth = document.getElementById('html').scrollWidth;
let scale = (595.28 - margin * 2) / srcwidth; // a4 pageSize 595.28

pdf.html(document.getElementById('html'), {
    backgroundColor: 'lightyellow',
    html2canvas: {
        scale: scale // default is window.devicePixelRatio,
    },
    x: margin,
    y: margin,
    callback: function () {
        window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jsPDF to generate a PDF matching HTML page dimensions (not accounting for multi-pages), including rendered images. Script depends on jsPDF v2.5.1 and html2canvas 1.4.1 (for rendering canvases, ie. for images etc):
// Create unconfigured PDF.
var pdf = new jsPDF();

```
// Generate PDF content from HTML body. 
pdf.html
(document.querySelector("body"),
  { // Config PDF page to match HTML page dimensions.
    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0], // PDF margins
    x: 0, y: 0, // PDF content origin offset from PDF page origin
    width: pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth(), // Generated PDF document's width in jsPDF units
    windowWidth: window.innerWidth // Page width in its browser window in CSS pixels
  }
);
```